# Specify argument and return types of dict transpose function

Tags: python, python-typing

This function transposes a given `dict` with `set` values:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def transpose_dict(dct: dict[int, set[int]]) -> dict[int, set[int]]:

    transposed = defaultdict(set)

    for key, value_set in dct.items():
        for inv_key in value_set:
            transposed[inv_key].add(key)
            
    return dict(transposed)
```

By the typing I used, the function is restricted to dictionaries with `int` keys and sets of `int` values only, although the type `int` itself is fairly irrelevant to the function implementation.

On the contrary, it would look pretty much the same even for `str`, `tuple`, etc. (or combinations thereof). The obvious option `dict[Any, set[Any]` seems too weak to me, since it does not reflect the swapping of the types of key and value.

How can I express a transposable `dict` type (`dict[A, set[B]]` ↔ `dict[B, set[A]]`) and its transposition type?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I wasn't clear on what you wanted until I deciphered your function implementation. Your example uses `int` only but you then move on to combine types

Comment: @joel I changed the wording, do you think it's better now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To define a transposable dictionary type and its transposition type, please use **TypeVar** from the typing module. Please try the below code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import TypeVar, Dict, Set

# Define type variables for the keys and values
K = TypeVar('K')
V = TypeVar('V')

def transpose_dict(dct: Dict[K, Set[V]]) -> Dict[V, Set[K]]:
    transposed = defaultdict(set)

    for key, value_set in dct.items():
        for inv_key in value_set:
            transposed[inv_key].add(key)
            
    return transposed
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand Generics and `TypeVar`. If we use `collections.abc.Mapping` or `collections.abc.MutableMapping` instead of the (deprecated) `typing.Dict`, it seems best to use `Mapping` as argument type, since we tread the argument read-only. But what is the best option for the return type?